# Linux kill() error unexpected

Tags: c++, linux, kill, sigkill, sigterm

Kill(pid, 0) seems to not set the error code correctly...as stated in man for kill

> Errors
>
> The kill() function shall fail if:
>
> EINVAL The value of the sig argument is an invalid or unsupported
>   signal number.
>    EPERM The process does not have permission to send the
>   signal to any receiving process.
>   ESRCH No process or process group can
>   be found corresponding to that specified by pid. The following
>   sections are informative.
>   [1](http://linux.die.net/man/3/kill)

It is returning ENOENT (no such file or directory) and then sometimes it returns EINTR (system call interrupted)...

Here is what I am doing:

```
kill(g_StatusInstance[i].pid, SIGTERM) == -1 && log_fatal_syscall("kill-sigterm");
kill(g_StatusInstance[i].pid, 0);

log_info_console( "Checking process for errors: %s\n", strerror(errno));

if(errno != ENOENT)
{
   kill(g_StatusInstance[i].pid, SIGKILL) == -1 && log_fatal_syscall("kill-sigkill");
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What is interrupting?  What do your signal handlers do?  What does log_fatal_syscall() do?  Something else is setting ENOENT... or did you really mean ESRCH?

Comment: Did you make sure `errno` is 0 before calling `kill`?

Comment: when i press ctrl c it calls the function that does this and basically there is a loop that loops through all the processes currently started by my program...then kills them

Comment: no i didnt set errno to anything before kill

Comment: "*It is returning ENOENT ... sometimes it returns EINTER*" - How do you know? I don't see you storing the result anywhere. A typical error with errno is not storinng a copy of it immediately. Subsequent library or system calls can set it if you don't examine it immediately.

Comment: im sorry im doing a log_info_console( "Checking process for errors: %s\n", strerror(errno)); right after the second call to kill - will update question.

Comment: Also, you aren't checking the return value from `kill()`. `errno` is only valid if `kill()` returns `-1`.

Comment: `kill(pid, 0)` only does error checking no signal is sent...

Comment: OK let me phrase it differently. Did you call any `errno`-setting function before `kill`, and if so, did yo check the result and set `errno` back to 0?

Comment: no - i updated the code in the question to include the call to strerror() - i called kill, the kill again to error check, then did the strerror...

Comment: "*`kill(pid, 0)` only does error checking*" - But you are ignoring the result of the error check! You must examine the return value from `kill()` to determine if an error occurred.

Comment: If kill is returning 0, then the value of `errno` is essential indeterminate. It could be ENOENT, it could be EINTR, it could be anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> > `Kill(pid, 0)` seems to not set the error code correctly ...
> >     It is returning ENOENT... EINTR
> >
> > Here is what I am doing:
> >
> > ```
> > ...
> > kill(g_StatusInstance[i].pid, 0);
> > log_info_console( "Checking process for errors: %s\n", strerror(errno));
> > ```
> >
> > Am I doing something wrong?

Yes. You are not checking the return value of the `kill()` system call. `kill()` does not set errno to any particular value in the successful case.

Try this:

```
if(kill(g_StatusInstance[i].pid, 0) == -1) {
  log_info_console( "Checking process for errors: %s\n", strerror(errno));
} else {
  log_info_console( "kill returned 0, process still alive\n" );
}
```

More generally, you ought to check the return value of every system call or library call, unless it is declared to return `void`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the discussion, your question is likely "Why did my `kill()` not generate the effect that I expected?"

In order to understand why that is happening, you should first try `strace` on the process which is the target of the `kill()`.  Attach it to your existing process by `pid` or invoke it under `strace`.  `strace` will show modifications to the signal mask and indicate when signals arrive.  If your signal is arriving, you should debug the process targeted by the `kill()` and try to understand what the installed/default signal handler is expected to do.